# Determine sets elements from their union and intersection using only math reasoning if possible

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have $E=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $A,B$ & $C$ are subsets of $E$ such that:

$$A\cup B = \{b,c,d,e\}$$
$$A\cap B = \{b,d\}$$
$$A\cup C = \{a,b,c,d\}$$
$$A\cap C = \{b,c\}$$

How to determine the sets $A, B$ and $C$.

Please, using only math and i mean by that not using logic, it's hard to explain what i mean by that. I determined them but without using any math i just knew that $A = \{b,c,d\}$ and $B=\{b,d,e\}$ and $C=\{b,c,a\}$ I wanna know is there any mathematical proof to determine them like using set theory laws...

Answer (score 3):

$A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap C\subseteq A$, therefore $\{b,c,d\}\subseteq A$. $A$ cannot contain $a$ or $e$ since $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $A\subseteq A\cup C$. So

$$A=\{b,c,d\}.$$

Since $A\cap B = \{b,d\}$ and $c\in A$, we get that $B$ contains $b$ and $d$ but does not contain $c$. $A\cup B=\{b,c,d,e\}$ implies that $B$ has to contain $e$ and can't contain any other element, since we already excluded $c$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$. So

$$B=\{b,d,e\}.$$

With exactly the same argument we find that

$$C=\{a,b,c\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Vincent Batens is perfectly good.  Alternatively, we can look at each element.

$a \notin A \cup B \Rightarrow (a \notin A \land a \notin B)$.  But $a \in A \cup C$, so $a \in C$.

$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C = \{b, d \} \cap \{b, c \} = \{b \}$, so $b \in A, B, C$.

$c \in A \cap C \Rightarrow (c \in A \land a \in C)$, but $(c \in A \land c \notin A \cap B) \Rightarrow c \notin B$.

$d \in A \cap B \Rightarrow (d \in A \land d \in B)$, but $(d \in A \land d \notin A \cap C) \Rightarrow d \notin C$.

$e \notin A \cup C \Rightarrow (e \notin A \land e \notin C)$.  But $e \in A \cup B,$ so $e \in B$.

Combining these results, $A = \{b, c, d \}, B = \{b, d, e \}, C = \{a, b, c \}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused as to what you're asking. It would be hard to do math without using logic.

We can observe that $A\supseteq A\cap B$, and $A\supseteq A\cap C$, so $\{b, c, d\}\subseteq A$. Now, $e\notin A\cup C$, so $e\notin A$. Can you see now why $e\in B$?

Following similar arguments you can arrive at what you desire.